# Grunt: More than 2 directories to compress

Tags: javascript, node.js, gruntjs

This is the current directory structure I have:

```
├── public
│   └── static
│       ├── bootstrap.min.js
│       ├── general.min.js
│       ├── html.js
│       ├── html.min.js
│       ├── plugins
│       │   ├── jquery.magnific-popup.min.js
│       │   ├── jquery.range.min.js
│       │   └── jquery.validate.min.js
│       ├── rcss
│       │   ├── bootstrap.min.css
│       │   ├── font-awesome.min.css
│       │   ├── html.css
│       │   ├── html.min.css
│       │   ├── jquery.range.css
│       │   ├── magnific-popup.css
│       │   ├── responsive.css
│       │   ├── style.css
│       │   └── yamm.css
│       └── voting
│           └── jquery.cookie.js
```

[and my Gruntfile.js](https://www.digitalocean.com/community/tutorials/how-to-setup-task-automation-with-grunt-and-node-js-on-a-vps):

```
module.exports = function(grunt) {

  grunt.initConfig({
    jsDir: 'public/static/',
    jsDistDir: 'public/static/',    
    cssDir: 'public/static/rcss/',
    cssDistDir: 'public/static/rcss/',
    pkg: grunt.file.readJSON('package.json'),
    concat: {
      js: {
        options: {
          separator: ';'
        },
        src: ['<%=jsDir%>*.js'],
        dest: '<%=jsDistDir%><%= pkg.name %>.js'
      },
      css: {
        src: ['<%=cssDir%>*.css'],
        dest: '<%=cssDistDir%><%= pkg.name %>.css'
      }
    },
    uglify: {
      options: {
        banner: '/*! <%= pkg.name %> <%=grunt.template.today("dd-mm-yyyy") %> */\n'
      },
      dist: {
        files: {
          '<%=jsDistDir%><%= pkg.name %>.min.js': ['<%= concat.js.dest %>']
        }
      }
    },
    cssmin: {
      add_banner: {
        options: {
          banner: '/*! <%= pkg.name %> <%=grunt.template.today("dd-mm-yyyy") %> */\n'
        },
        files: {
          '<%=cssDistDir%><%= pkg.name %>.min.css': ['<%= concat.css.dest %>']
        }
      }
    },
    watch: {
    files: ['<%=jsDir%>*.js', '<%=cssDir%>*.css'],
    tasks: ['concat', 'uglify', 'cssmin']
    }
  });

  grunt.loadNpmTasks('grunt-contrib-concat');
  grunt.loadNpmTasks('grunt-contrib-uglify');
  grunt.loadNpmTasks('grunt-contrib-cssmin');
  grunt.loadNpmTasks('grunt-contrib-watch');

  grunt.registerTask('default', [
    'concat',
    'uglify',
    'cssmin',
    'watch'
  ]);

};
```

This takes only the 2 .js files within the "Static" directory. 
Is it possible to tell grunt to grab the files within "Plugins" and "voting" folders too [without typing every folder separately](https://gruntjs.com/configuring-tasks#files-object-format)?

Comment: H-hey R-r-r-ick.... I think you should... I think you should... you should... try adding double asterisk.. to the path.. ohhhh boy... like... `(/path/example/**/*.js)`... this will glob all directories under this one and their files... aw jeez R-rick

Comment: Toda Morty, oved :)